# I want to translate the title of a Korean children's reader into English

Tags: grammar, translation

The title is 떼쓰지말고 말하렴. I searched several dictionaries fruitlessly to find a verb spelled 떼쓰다.

Comment: Please read the definitions of [떼쓰다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=51861&nation=eng), [말다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=72580), [-고](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=78583&nation=eng), [말하다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=62103&nation=eng), and [-렴](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=79340), and try translating "떼쓰지 말고 말하렴."

Answer (score 0):

"Don't throw a fit" is what you want for 떼쓰지말고 part.

떼쓰다 would be to throw a fit.

Answer (score 0):

떼쓰다 is similar to nagging (something) - urging and demanding with emotional harassment.